# Should it be "still in" or " still at" in the following?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> When I arrived home, Mom was *still in/at* her yoga class.

Should one use *in* or *at* in this situation. And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to disagree with Kate Bunting, but, at least in spoken American English, both "in" and "at" are acceptable. She is both where the class takes place ("at"), and she is a part of the class ("in").

According to Ngram, "in class" is far more common in written American English, but I do not rely too heavily on Ngram. First, it cannot cope with speech, and my impression is that "at class" is quite common in American speech. Second, Ngram is independent of context, and context may influence the choice of preposition.

Comment: "at class" isn't very common, but "at a class" is probably more common

Comment: In the context of the question, "a class" does not make sense. The woman being mentioned probably only has one yoga class scheduled at a particular time. I do agree in general that "at a class" is far more common than "at class."

Comment: fine, so "at the class". This isn't just being "in class" generally, but rather at a specific class.

Comment: I'd forgotten that Americans say _in school_ where the British would say _at school_.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the yoga class is taking place elsewhere, *at* would be usual. (She is at the place where the class is held, not at home.)

If the speaker was in the same building, perhaps having just attended a different class, they might say 'Mom is still *in* her yoga class'.